# Run cron job on cpanel with php7 version

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, magento2.2

I want to setup cron job on cpanel admin with php7 version. My php script for cron requires php 7.0 or above to run.  The problem is that the path to php7 cannot be found. I have already selected php 7.0 as current version in cpanel. I do not have access to ssl.

what I have done is similar to this this

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php "/home/username/public_html"/myjob.php >> "/home/username"/myjob.log
```

This works for scripts which runs with php 5.6 but my problem is that the job `myjob.php` requires php 7.0. I tried to run with `php7`, `php70`, `php7.0` but none run. I tried to run like this.

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php7 "/home/username/public_html"/myjob.php >> "/home/username"/myjob.log
```

My problem is that I cannot find the the path to php7. Where is the path to this version? How can I run this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Command to run a PHP 7.0 cron job:

`/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/myjob.php >> /home/username/myjob.log`

### Command to run a PHP 7.1 cron job:

`/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/myjob.php >> /home/username/myjob.log`

### Command to run a PHP 7.2 cron job:

`/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/myjob.php >> /home/username/myjob.log`

Answer (score 4):

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php70 /home/username/public_html/myjob.php >> /home/username/myjob.log
```

You will also find there is some examples inside cpanel's cron job page.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change it to

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/myjob.php >> 
/home/username/myjob.log
```

Hope this helps!